# Qt6 Painting issue in windows with nativeEvent WM_NCCALCSIZE

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, pyqt6

I worked on Windows platform. If I used both qt window flags and windows api to get a frameless window, like:

```cpp
this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

and

```cpp
SetWindowLong((HWND) this->winId(), GWL_STYLE, style | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_CAPTION | CS_DBLCLKS | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_OVERLAPPED);
```

Then I use WM_NCCALCSIZE to tell windows client rect size like:

```cpp
/* get border x-size */
int tx = getResizeBorderThickness(hWnd);
/* get border y-size */
int ty = getResizeBorderThickness(hWnd, false);
/* sub real client size with border size */
rect->top += ty;
rect->bottom -= ty;
rect->left += tx;
rect->right -= tx;
```

It works fine when `PyQt/Qt<=6.4.2(probably)`.

result_img_PyQt6.4.2
[image]

result_img_C++ Qt6.3.2
[image]

And you will get a wrong painted window when using `PyQt/Qt6.6.1`

result_img_PyQt6.6.1

[image]

result_img_C++ Qt6.6.1
[image]

C++ Test code here

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dwmapi.lib")

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    auto style = GetWindowLong((HWND) this->winId(), GWL_STYLE);
    SetWindowLong((HWND) this->winId(),
                  GWL_STYLE,
                  style | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_CAPTION | CS_DBLCLKS | WS_THICKFRAME
                      | WS_OVERLAPPED);
    SetWindowPos((HWND) this->winId(),
                 HWND_TOP,
                 0,
                 0,
                 0,
                 0,
                 SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    this->showMaximized();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool isMaximized(HWND hWnd)
{
    WINDOWPLACEMENT windowPlacement;
    windowPlacement.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
    bool ret = GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &windowPlacement);
    if (!ret) {
        return false;
    }

    return windowPlacement.showCmd == SW_MAXIMIZE;
}

QWindow *findWindow(HWND hWnd)
{
    if (!hWnd)
        return nullptr;
    auto windows = QGuiApplication::topLevelWindows();
    if (windows.size() == 0)
        return nullptr;
    int id = int(hWnd);
    foreach (auto w, windows) {
        if (int(w->winId()) == id) {
            return w;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int getResizeBorderThickness(HWND hWnd, bool hor = true)
{
    auto window = findWindow(hWnd);
    if (!window) {
        return 0;
    }
    auto frame = hor ? SM_CXSIZEFRAME : SM_CYSIZEFRAME;
    auto size = GetSystemMetrics(frame) + GetSystemMetrics(92);
    if (size > 0)
        return size;
    int res = 0;
    DwmIsCompositionEnabled(&res);
    auto thickness = res ? 8 : 4;
    return int(thickness * window->devicePixelRatio());
}

bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, qintptr *result)
{
    if (eventType != "windows_generic_MSG") {
        return false;
    }
    MSG *msg = (MSG *) message;
    if (msg->hwnd == nullptr)
        return false;
    switch (msg->message) {
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE: {
        auto isMax = ::isMaximized(msg->hwnd);
        auto setRectMax = [](HWND hWnd, LPRECT rect) {
            int tx = getResizeBorderThickness(hWnd);
            int ty = getResizeBorderThickness(hWnd, false);
            rect->top += ty;
            rect->bottom -= ty;
            rect->left += tx;
            rect->right -= tx;
        };
        if (msg->wParam) {
            LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS rect = (LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS) (msg->lParam);
            if (isMax) {
                setRectMax(msg->hwnd, rect->rgrc);
            }
        } else {
            LPRECT rect = (LPRECT) (msg->lParam);
            if (isMax) {
                setRectMax(msg->hwnd, rect);
            }
        }
        *result = msg->wParam ? 0 : WVR_REDRAW;
        return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This issue will occur when using both `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` and `SetWindowLong`,but deleting `SetWindLong` calling will lose the window animation
Is there a way to achieve the same effect as version 6.4.2 when using PyQt6.6.2/Qt6.6.2 while retaining the `SetWindowLong` calling

Comment: This issue may be caused by the patch of https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-84466 and has been reported to qt bug track

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug [QTBUG-120196](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-120196)

Patch added and merged

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can I ask what your final code looks like for this to work? I've been trying to achieve the same thing even with the patch but if I force the rect like this in WM_NCCALCSIZE Qt doesn't seem to realize we went maximized and just freezes.